# what would be a quick way to do nested splitting of brackets in python?

Tags: python

I have a file of the following format:

```
ID1 { some text }
ID2 { some text }
```

They don't have to come line by line format, so that we can have:

```
ID1 { some [crlf]
text [crlf]
}

ID2 [crlf] { some t [crlf]
ex [crlf]
t}
```

and so on, meaning `some text` can be more than one line and there could be a `CRLF` immediately following `ID`. The main invariant is that all IDs are enclosed by `{` `}`.
The thing is that `some text` itself could have `{` and `}` in it.

What would be a quick way to take such a file and separate it into a list of strings, each being `ID { text }`, while taking into account nested brackets?

Taking into account some error analysis, in case brackets are not balanced, would be great.

Comment: can you by anyway format this file ,i mean change how data are written in this file ?, because this file look like a mess !!! and i think that before thinking how can you retrieve data you should first think about how to write data to make retrieving it easier.

Comment: Does `some text` ever contain a `crlf`? If not, strip those out and things become a lot easier...

Answer (score 4):

Using pyparsing you can knock this out in about 6 lines, and then get on with your other work. Here are two variations on a solution, depending on how you want the parse results structured:

```
data = """ID1 { some text } ID2 { some {with some more text nested in braces} text }"""

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphanums, dictOf, nestedExpr, originalTextFor

# identifier starts with any alpha, followed by any alpha, num, or '_'
ident = Word(alphas,alphanums+"_")

# Solution 1
# list of items is a dict of pairs of idents and nested {}'s 
# - returns {}'s expressions as nested structures
itemlist = dictOf(ident, nestedExpr("{","}"))
items = itemlist.parseString(data)
print items.dump()

"""
prints:
[['ID1', ['some', 'text']], ['ID2', ['some', ['with', 'some', 'more', ...
- ID1: ['some', 'text']
- ID2: ['some', ['with', 'some', 'more', 'text', 'nested', 'in', 'braces'], 'text']
"""

# Solution 2
# list of items is a dict of pairs of idents and nested {}'s 
# - returns {}'s expressions as strings of text extract from the 
# original input string
itemlist = dictOf(ident, originalTextFor(nestedExpr("{","}")))
items = itemlist.parseString(data)
print items.dump()

"""
prints:
[['ID1', '{ some text }'], ['ID2', '{ some {with some more text nested in ...
- ID1: { some text }
- ID2: { some {with some more text nested in braces} text }
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple question of "how do I write a rescursive decent parser that matches brackets.

Given this grammar:

```
STMT_LIST := STMT+
STMT := ID '{' DATA '}'
DATA := TEXT | STMT
ID := [a-z0-9]+
TEXT := [^}]*
```

A parser might look like:

```
import sys
import re

def parse(data):
    """
    STMT
    """
    while data:
        data, statement_id, clause = parse_statement(data)
        print repr((statement_id, clause))

def consume_whitespace(data):
    return data.lstrip()

def parse_statement(data):
    m = re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', data)
    if not m:
        raise ValueError, "No ID found"
    statement_id = m.group(0)
    data = consume_whitespace(data[len(statement_id):])
    data, clause = parse_clause(data)
    return consume_whitespace(data), statement_id, clause

def parse_clause(data):
    clause = []
    if not data.startswith('{'):
        raise ValueError, "No { found"
    data = data[1:]
    closebrace = data.index('}')
    try:
        openbrace = data.index('{')
    except ValueError:
        openbrace = sys.maxint
    while openbrace < closebrace:
        clause.append(data[:openbrace])
        data, subclause = parse_clause(data[openbrace:])
        clause.append(subclause)

        closebrace = data.index('}')
        try:
            openbrace = data.index('{')
        except ValueError:
            openbrace = sys.maxint
    clause.append(data[:closebrace])
    data = data[closebrace+1:]
    return data, clause

parse("ID { foo { bar } }")
parse("ID { foo { bar } } baz { tee fdsa { fdsa } }")
```

This is a nasty parser to be honest. If you were to structure it nicer you would end up with a proper token stream from a lexxer and pass that to the actual parser. As it is the 'token stream' is just a string that we strip info off the start of.

I would recommend looking at pyparsing if you wanted anything more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

[regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is out of the question, [obviously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_Hierarchy). Have you looked at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)?

[EDIT]

OTOH this might work:

```
from functools import wraps


def transition(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def trans(state, *args, **kwargs):
        command = method(state, *args, **kwargs)
        state.__class__ = command(state)
    return trans


class State(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        state = object.__new__(cls)
        state._identities = []
        return state

def unchanged(state):
    return state.__class__

def shifting(identity):
    def command(state):
        return identity
    return command

def pushing(identity, afterwards=None):
    def command(state):
        state._identities.append(afterwards or state.__class__)
        return identity
    return command

def popped(state):
    return state._identities.pop()


##############################################################################


import re
tokenize = re.compile(flags=re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE, pattern=r"""
    (?P<word>       \w+ ) |
    (?P<braceleft>  {   ) |
    (?P<braceright> }   ) |
    (?P<eoi>        $   ) |
    (?P<error>      \S  ) # catch all (except white space)
""").finditer

def parse(parser, source, builder):
    for each in tokenize(source):
        dispatch = getattr(parser, each.lastgroup)
        dispatch(each.group(), builder)


class ParsingState(State):
    def eoi(self, token, *args):
        raise ValueError('premature end of input in parsing state %s' %
            self.__class__.__name__
        )
    def error(self, token, *args):
        raise ValueError('parsing state %s does not understand token %s' % (
            self.__class__.__name__, token
        ))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def raiser(token, *args):
            raise ValueError(
                'parsing state %s does not understand token "%s" of type %s' %
                (self.__class__.__name__, token, name)
            )
        return raiser


class Id(ParsingState):
    @transition
    def word(self, token, builder):
        builder.add_id(token)
        return shifting(BeginContent)
    @transition
    def eoi(self, token, builder):
        return shifting(DoneParsing)

class BeginContent(ParsingState):
    @transition
    def braceleft(self, token, builder):
        return shifting(Content)

class Content(ParsingState):
    @transition
    def word(self, token, builder):
        builder.add_text(token)
        return unchanged
    @transition
    def braceleft(self, token, builder):
        builder.add_text(token)
        return pushing(PushedContent)
    @transition
    def braceright(self, token, builder):
        return shifting(Id)

class PushedContent(Content):
    @transition
    def braceright(self, token, builder):
        builder.add_text(token)
        return popped

class DoneParsing(ParsingState):
    pass

##############################################################################


class Entry(object):
    def __init__(self, idname):
        self.idname = idname
        self.text = []
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s { %s }' % (self.idname, ' '.join(self.text))

class Builder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.entries = []
    def add_id(self, id_token):
        self.entries.append(Entry(id_token))
    def add_text(self, text_token):
        self.entries[-1].text.append(text_token)


##############################################################################


if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_content = """
    id1 { some text } id2 {
    some { text }
    }
    """

    builder = Builder()
    parse(Id(), file_content, builder)
    for entry in builder.entries:
        print entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the brute force method, with error detection included or indicated:

```
# parsebrackets.py
def parse_brackets(data):
    # step 1: find the 0-nesting-level { and }
    lpos = []
    rpos = []
    nest = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(data):
        if c == '{':
            if nest == 0:
                lpos.append(i)
            nest += 1
        elif c == '}':
            nest -= 1
            if nest < 0:
                raise Exception('too many } at offset %d' % i)
            if nest == 0:
                rpos.append(i)
    if nest > 0:
        raise Exception('too many { in data')
    prev = -1
    # step 2: extract the pieces
    for start, end in zip(lpos, rpos):
        key = data[prev+1:start].strip()
        # insert test for empty key here
        text = data[start:end+1]
        prev = end
        yield key, text
    if data[prev+1:].strip():
        raise Exception('non-blank text after last }')
```

Output:

```
>>> from parsebrackets import parse_brackets as pb
>>> for k, t in pb(' foo   {bar {zot\n}} guff {qwerty}'):
...    print repr(k), repr(t)
...
'foo' '{bar {zot\n}}'
'guff' '{qwerty}'
>>>
```